# Reproduce the same syntax of PHP arrays with C# lists

Tags: c#, nested-lists

I've been trying to figure out how to reproduce the following code from PHP:

```
$array[0]['name'] = "Array 0";
$array[0]['color'] = "#505050";
$array[0]['font'] = "Arial";
```

To C#. I've been looking and found lists and nested lists but I don't understand how the second list knows that it's the child of the first one.

If anyone can help me, thanks!

Comment: [Jagged array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays) or [Rectangular array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays)? And will a list of object with property be enought here?

Comment: Would you dump, sanitise and [edit] the value that are store in this array on php so we have clear understanding of what you are trying to store?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class in my example the "Style Class" and create a List.

```
static void Main()
{
    var items = new List<Style>();
    items.Add(new Style { Name = "Array 0", Color = "#505050", Font = "Arial" });
}

public class Style
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string Font { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn exact equivalent, maybe it could be array of `NameValueCollection`;

```
NameValueCollection[] nameValueCollectionArray = new NameValueCollection[10];
nameValueCollectionArray[0].Add("Name","Value");
var value = nameValueCollectionArray[0]["Name"];
```

But, I strongly suggest you to create a model class and build collection from it.

Answer (score 0):

Either use what Tom Baires suggested (using a class and then list of class elements) or use a Tuple

```
var something = new Tuple<string, string, string>("Array 0", "#505050", "Arial");
```

More information here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx